# how to motion track in after effects

Tags: video, after-effects, animation

How to motion track and put a 3d model on a video so it looks like it belongs there. I have a 3d sequence wolf that I am importing through element and once I get it into ae, how do I track the video and put the model on it so it looks like it belongs there? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Are you trying to use Mocha? What have you tried?

Comment: [Maybe this could help you out](http://youtu.be/Xy3m7I8jBuM)

Comment: No I'm not sure what is best and frankly i don't know how to track. What is the best and easiest way to track and put a 3d model in the video so it looks like it belongs there? Thanks

Comment: @PandaAB Joonases tutorial is about as good as it gets. [You can do it in blender as well](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-to-camera-tracking/#.U9sQPPldV8E)

Comment: Did you try google? Seriously, this question probably has tons of different implementations and even more tutorials exampling how to do this.